# What is the meaning of 1015 in the Twilight Zone reboot?

Tags: the-twilight-zone, the-twilight-zone-2019

In the rebooted *Twilight Zone*, the number 1015 seems to appear in several episodes. Sometimes it's the time, in another episode it was the licence plate number of a police car.

Within *The Twilight Zone*, is there any significance or hidden meaning behind the number?

Comment: https://twilightzone.fandom.com/wiki/1015 - "*No explanation has as yet been offered for the constant repetition of the number.*"

Comment: My instinct is that it'll (eventually) prove to be a plot point of some description, in a future episode.

Comment: Could be like "47" and Star Trek: https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/47

Comment: @Valorum Even so, it's likely to be someone's birthday.

Comment: @Spencer - Sure, or their locker code, or the name of the room that they learned screenwriting in

Comment: It might be a police ten code (10-15) meaning either "civil disturbance" or "prisoner in custody" in different parts of space-time.